# Installing GloMoSim in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu

I am new to ubuntu and have version 11.10 installed.  I need to install glomosim v2.03 on my laptop.  Can any one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Install Parsec by typing

```
    sudo apt-get install parsec47
```

2) Download GloMoSim from http://pcl.cs.ucla.edu/projects/glomosim/obtaining_glomosim.html

3) Change into the glomosim-2.03/glomosim/main

```
    cd glomosim-2.03/glomosim/main
```

4) Build by typing:

```
    make
```

To the set the environment variables edit the .bashrc in your home directory and type for example:

```
    export PCC_DIRECTORY="/home/mydir"
```

and save the .bashrc file. Logout and login again then type the following at the command line to make sure the environment variable is set:

```
    echo $PCC_DIRECTORY
```

you should see /home/mydir

Comment: Everything was fine until `make`. After searching around I figured out that there was one thing left. `sudo make install`. Thanks